# Layer visibility shortcut in Photoshop

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-photoshop

Is there a way to set a keyboard shortcut to toggle layer visibility in Photoshop (CS3)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There isn't a shortcut bound to this action by default; but if you go to the Keyboard Shortcuts configuration (Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts) under 'Layers' there is a 'Hide Layers' option where you can bind your own shortcut.

Answer (score 6):

Mac = <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> toggles selected layer visibility 
Mac = <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> turns all layers' visibility on regardless of layer selection.

PC = <kbd>ctl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> 
PC = <kbd>ctl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>

Comment: This feature was added in some version; which one?

Comment: works in 2019 cc

Answer (score 4):

I don't think Photoshop has a default hotkey for showing/hiding a certain layer.  You can, however, create your own action to do this, and just bind it to a key.

Answer (score 1):

I have software "photoshop assistant". It can bind any key to show/hide a particular layer...and other cool stuff too. You can check it. I tried creating an action, it works but you have to bind choose the shortcut key from the F(x) keys and what is worse, you should choose two different keys for "hide" and for "show layer". It's boring...

Comment: What do you mean? Is this a plugin? A script? How did you set this up?